# Odoo15 : Displaying different views in different contexts

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to display a form view of a model returned by an action in a menu and display another form view of the same model in a different context ( by clicking on a button) but I'm getting the two different views displayed side by side.

First, I have tried inheriting the first view and used different priorities in , but I was always getting the inherited view displayed even if it has the highest priority

Second, I have defined different form views of same model without any inheriting I used the XML code below :

```
<record id="client_payment_form_view_for_bl" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">payment.bl.form</field>
    <field name="model">client.payment</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="100"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Paiements client">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <group name="group1">
                        <field name="partner_id" readonly="1"/>
                        <field name="payment_type"/>
                        <field name="date_payment" />
                        <field name="payment_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    </group>
                    <group name="group2">
                        <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="total_to_pay"/>
                        <field name="total_payments"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="client_payment_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">client.payment.form</field>
    <field name="model">client.payment</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Paiements client">
            <header>
                <button name="action_confirm" string="Confirmer" class="btn-primary" type="object" states="draft"/>
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm"/>
            </header>
            <sheet>

                <div class="oe_title">
                    <label for="name"/>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="name" placeholder="Référence"/>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <group>
                    <group name="group1">
                        <field name="partner_id"/>
                        <field name="payment_type"/>
                        <field name="picking_ids" widget="many2many_tags"
                               domain="[('picking_type_code','=','outgoing')]"/>
                        <field name="date_payment"/>
                        <field name="payment_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>

                    </group>
                    <group name="group2">
                        <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="total_to_pay"/>
                        <field name="total_payments"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </sheet>
            <div class="oe_chatter">
                <field name="message_follower_ids"/>
                <field name="activity_ids"/>
                <field name="message_ids"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Here is the code of action associated to the menu :

```
<record id="client_payment_act_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Paiements client</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">client.payment</field>

    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="module_name.client_payment_form_view"/>
    <field name="view_ids" eval="[(5,0,0),
(0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('module_name.client_payment_tree_view')}),
(0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('module_name.client_payment_form_view')})]"/>
    <field name="context">{'form_view_ref': 'module_name.client_payment_form_view'}</field>
</record>
```

Here is the Python code for returned view of the button of type object :

```
    def register_payment(self):
        view_ref = self.env.ref('module_name.client_payment_form_view_for_bl').id
        return {
            'res_model': 'client.payment',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': view_ref,
        }
```

I need help to display one of the "form" views, each in its appropriate context

Comment: Having two independent views should be fine, but even inhering views should work with `mode='primary`. But let's stick to the 2 indep. views idea. Your code looks fine. Does the menu (and action) work as expected? Does the button action not work?

Comment: Yes, both menu and action work fine.

Comment: Are they working was meant in regard to the views. So in which of the two cases (menu or button) are you getting the wrong view?

Comment: I meant by working fine, there are no errors appearing. However, in both views (button view and the menu view) I'm getting the view displayed in the wrong way (One over the other)

Comment: I presume `client_payment_form_view` is always shown?

Comment: I reinstalled the module, it seems to work fine now. Thank you !

Comment: Okay, sometimes module updates work like a charm ;-)